# unable to sent SMS using AT Commands in hyperterminal by using TCAM GSM Modem

Tags: unicode, sms, serial-port, gsm, hyperterminal

I am facing the problem while running the AT-commands in Hyperterminal when i enter the following commands

```
AT
AT+CMGF=1
AT+CSCS="GSM"
AT+CMGS="03215836031"
>TEST <CTRL-Z>
```

it returns the following result

**Result: +CMGS: 136**

and i received the sms on my cell.

but when i use the following sequence of commands it gives me the error

```
AT
AT+CMGF=1
AT+CSMP=17,167,0,8
AT+CSCS="UCS2"
AT+CMGS="03215836031"
```

**Result: +CMS ERROR: 305**

I don't know what is going wrong with these commands. i have googled a lot but not find any solution.

Answer (score 0):

+CMS ERROR: 305 is a text format mode error.

```
AT
AT+CMGF=1
AT+CSMP=17,167,0,8
AT+CSCS="UCS2"
AT+CMGS="Unicode" Mobile no and SMS text must be convert to hex code.
```

I have tested successfully and sent SMS to any language.